# cannot convert parameter from const char to lnt

Tags: sql, c++-cli

```
SqlConnection^ cond = gcnew SqlConnection(L"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=vagifd;Integrated Security=True");


             cond->Open();

             SqlCommand^ comd = gcnew SqlCommand("select * from dbo.students order by name asc;", cond);

             SqlDataReader^ quer = comd->ExecuteReader();



             int a=1;
             try{
                 while(quer->Read()){

                     label1->Text += quer->GetString("name");
                     a++;
                 }
             }
             catch(Exception^ ex){
                 MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
             }
```

i use microsoft sql server 2008 and visual studio 2010. columns in my table are char type. what is the problem ? the error line is

```
label1->Text += quer->GetString("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are attempting to pass a string to a method that takes an integer. Pass the column number:

```
quer->GetString(42)
```

I can't tell which column corresponds to "name". It is poor practice to use "*" because it makes your code depend on the order of columns in "dbo.students". And, if a large column (such as a jpeg picture of the student) is added, performance will suffer needlessly. Just list the columns you need in the order you want.

Perhaps you'd rather use the Item property:

```
quer->default["name"]
```

However, it returns an object, not a string.

#### Item Property

In C#, you could index `quer` but not in [C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7xfeyax.aspx)

> Visual C++ does not contain indexers; it has indexed properties. To
>   consume a C# indexer, access the indexer as if it were an indexed
>   property.

In this case, you index the [SqlDataReader.Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f01t4cfy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) property, which is the default so you use `default` as the property.

Comment: I corrected it to "default" since it is the default indexed property.